# Why is Robocode running at max 1-2FPS (with target FPS slider set to 30 FPS)?

Tags: java, windows, frame-rate, robocode

Currently testing [Robocode](https://robocode.sourceforge.io/) (fresh C:\ installation).

I've compiled a test robot and a sentry. However, when running battle with the robot, sentry and an interactive bot, my max FPS is 1-2FPS (read from the output at the top of the screen).

I'm aware of the FPS slider at the bottom of the screen, and it's currently set to 30 - but this does not move the game above 1-2FPS.
[image]

Can anybody suggest a way to improve RoboCode's performance on my machine?

Running Windows 10 w/DX12 on an Intel Core i7-4930k with 16384MB Ram and a GeForce GTX 760.